# ハッシュの隣り合ったvalueの差が多きものを求めたい

Tags: ruby

タイトルが分かりづらくてすみません。

```
hash = {a=>2.4, b=>3.5, c=>4.3, d=>5.0, e=>2.2}
```

上記のようなハッシュの場合だと、aとbの差が1.1、bとcの差が0.8、cとdが0.7、dとeが2.8になるのでdもしくはeを出力したいのですが求め方が思いつきません。

これを求める方法を是非教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

隣り合うとはaであればbとの差、bであればaとcとの差、cであればbとdとの差ということです。
説明が分かりづらく申し訳ありません。

Comment: 隣り合う要素というものをどう定義してるのでしょうか?

Comment: ハッシュの中身がきれいに整列しているとは限らないので、今回の質問も例えば **ハッシュのキーを辞書順に参照して**隣り合う…」のような書き方をすると意図がより正確に伝わる気がします。 (並び順を気にせず代入、参照できるのがハッシュの特徴なので)

Comment: 実は、 ruby の hash は、たしか投入順序を記憶してたような気がします。少なくともある一定のバージョンでは。

Comment: いつからだったか調べていませんが、かなり以前からRubyのハッシュは順序が保持されています。「[ハッシュに含まれる要素の順序が保持されるようになりました。 ハッシュにキーが追加された順序で列挙します。](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/Hash.html)」

Comment: 調べてみると 1.9 以降は保証されているようですね、失礼しました。 - [Hash#keysの順番は保証されるのか？ - Qiira](https://qiita.com/ongaeshi/items/a57b6ab166b3c4bc360d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash = {a: 2.4, b: 3.5, c: 4.3, d: 5.0, e: 2.2}

result = hash.each_cons(2).map do |kv1, kv2|
  value_diff = (kv1[1] - kv2[1]).abs
  [[kv1[0], kv2[0]], value_diff]
end.max_by { |_, v| v }

p result[0]
```

上記を実行すると、 `[:d, :e]` を得られるはずです。